# Array Formula that also runs calculation on each cell's column header

Tags: function, if-statement, google-sheets, lambda, sum

I work at a school and at the end of each semester we need to total up instructional hours for each student in each class, then get the sum for the whole class.  We keep our attendance on a Google Sheet each semester, so I can use fancy functions to do this.  This function has worked perfectly the last couple years:

=arrayformula(sum(countifs([data range],{"","T","*all *","*no *"})))

I run this at the beginning of a row and it counts all instances where a student (or the entire class) would be counted as present, but doesn't count anything else; just like I need it (students are counted as present if the cell is left blank).  I run this function on each row (for each individual student) and then run a quick sum at the bottom of the sheet and it's all good to go.

Well, this worked because our classes were all 1-hour long every day.  Starting this semester, they are either 1 hour and 20 minutes or 32 minutes depending on the day of the week (each class has one occurrence that is an hour twenty and one that is thirty-two minutes each week).  So the above function no longer works as it just totals how many classes a student showed up for.  I now need something that will do that, but also multiply the result of each cell (1 or 0) by either 1.33 or .53 depending on the day of the week.  This can be done by referencing each column's header, which has the date attached and running a WEEKDAY parameter nested in an IF parameter like so (using a class that has the longer instance on a Friday for example):

(if((weekday(Z$1))=6, 1.33, 0.53))

I put that together into a function that works:

=countifs(Z2,{"","T","*all *","*no *"})*(if((weekday(Z$1))=6, 1.33, 0.53))

... but I will have to create a dummy column next to the column that has each date's attendance data, tailor the formula to the column next to it and copy and paste the formula all the way down the column.  I should only need to change the formula once per sheet, but I'll still need to create dummy columns next to each date and then run this formula by hand on each column.  After all that, then I can sum up each row.  It works... but I want something less time-intensive and prone to error.

What I am hoping for is a function that does what I have now (for single cells), but runs each portion of this function on each individual cell across an entire row of data after I add it to the beginning of the row and then, preferably, sums up the total hours at the end (should just be able to add a SUM parameter to the beginning of the function?); all in a one-cell function.  I have tried using an array like I had before (in the first formula above), but the problem there (there's probably more than one problem), is that I can't get the function to reference each cell's header and run the IF function, I can only get the array to work on the COUNTIF portion of the function.  Maybe this whole thing needs to be a script instead?

I hope what I am asking for makes sense and here is a link to a sample of the data I am using:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12fTE_AMlKtlqc_KToYB5TkvpYwFzON9Q6vvRfnDlr0A/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you for reading and I hope there is a reasonable solution to what I'm asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(BYROW(B2:N15, LAMBDA(x, SUM(
 REGEXMATCH(x, "^$|no .+|all .+|T")*
 IF(WEEKDAY(B1:N1)=6, 1.33, 0.53)))))
```

[image]

Comment: YES!  I had to change the formula to match the correct day and data range to this:

=INDEX(BYROW(C2:O2, LAMBDA(x, SUM(REGEXMATCH(x, "^$|no .+|all .+|T")*IF(WEEKDAY(C$1:O$1)=2, 1.33, 0.53)))))

And then it works!  Thank you so much and I look forward to learning about the different parameters here I don't really have experience with yet (e.g., INDEX, LAMBDA, REGEXMATCH).  Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, upon using it more today, I found that I spoke too quickly and presumptuously and didn't actually need to change anything besides the number attached to the WEEKDAY parameter.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Is anyone able to explain why the function needs to be wrapped in the INDEX parameter?  It doesn't seem to need to be there at all, but the function will not work without it.  I found that using INDEX with just a number outputs just the same number entered (e.g., =INDEX(34) outputs 34), so it makes sense that in this function it just outputs the number provided by the rest of the function, but I can't figure out why that needs to be there in the first place for the whole thing to work.

Comment: @Beta if it works for you without it then you can drop it. I used it because of the multiplication of arrays and left it as a precaution

Comment: No, it doesn't work without it and I was trying to figure out why it was needed.  I'm not super well-versed in this yet and just looking at the INDEX parameter itself didn't explain why it seems to be necessary the way this function is written.  The way you wrote it works wonderfully and I am not looking to question that choice, only learn more from my betters :)

Comment: @Beta we use ARRAYFORMULA whenever we work with arrays/ranges so that the sheet would recognize it that we intend to process multiple cells. INDEX is same s AF just shorter. then there are also exclusions... for example FILTER,SORT,QUERY does not need AF wrapping

Comment: Aaaah ok, I can see that now.  I went in and replaced INDEX with ARRAYFORMULA and it works just the same; I didn't get that from reading INDEX's documentation.  Thanks for explaining!